# Python Sniffer and RST vector

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I wrote a sniffer in python using only what is built into Kali 1.05. Sniffer sees all traffic (except I had to use a script to enter promiscuous mode) and I want to RST a single machine connecting to an address. Below is a bit of the sniffer code. I've tried injecting the header (using an IP and MAC address I don't have) set to any mounted device and I get an error[6]:No such device or address. I wrote out the packet by hand in hex to see if that helped, but I get the same error (I can't attach that portion of code so please don't ask). Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
import threading, os, sys, socket, struct, binascii, time

class atk(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        pkt_type = [0x003]
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(pkt_type[0]))
        def run(self):
            self.atk_msg = ""
            while True:
                msg = self.sock.recv(65565)
                print "PROTOCOL Layer 2-3: ", self.decomp2(self.decomp(msg)), " 3-4: ", self.decomp3(self.decomp(msg))
        def decomp(self, msg):
            return list(binascii.hexlify(msg))
        def decomp3(self, msg):
            if msg[46] == '0' and msg[47] == '6':
                return "TCP"
        def decomp2(self, msg):
            if msg[24] == '0' and msg[25] == '8' and msg[26] == '0' and msg[27] == '0':
                return "IP  "
            if msg[24] == '0' and msg[25] == '8' and msg[26] == '0' and msg[27] == '6':
                return "ARP "
            if msg[24] == '8' and msg[25] == '6' and msg[26] == 'd' and msg[27] == 'd':
                return "IPV6"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = atk()
    a.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface was still connected to an IP on the interface. It took some doing but I removed all traces of the address without turning off the interface and that worked. It now doesn't attempt to distinguish between addresses. I blanket out the 
/etc/network/(interface) file and restarted and my construct worked. I will need to write code to blanket it out, reload the interface, send packet, revert to prior address, but I'm not certain in basic python that this is possible. I have no network use on this so I might make my own in gcc or not worry about it since it is a sniffer in python, which is a bit impractical anyway.